# Creating Radio Buttons in Basic Assets

Tags: webcenter-sites

I am trying to add a radio button to my basic asset using [following steps in point #15.2.3.10](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/doc.1111/e29634/data_designbasictype.htm#WBCSD1498).

I want to include static list of items, so as per documentation I have used `OPTIONDESCRIPTIONS` parameter:

```
<PROPERTY NAME="gender" DESCRIPTION="Gender">
    <STORAGE TYPE="VARCHAR" LENGTH="4"/>
    <INPUTFORM TYPE="RADIO" SOURCETYPE="STRING" OPTIONVALUES="male,female,others" OPTIONDESCRIPTIONS="male,female,others"/>
</PROPERTY>
```

But when I create new basic asset in Contributor UI, I get error:
[image]

Can you please highlight me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For display radio button in basic asset,You have to use "RBDESCRIPTIONS and RBVALUES" attribute instead using "OPTIONDESCRIPTIONS ,OPTIONVALUES"(used for drop down the list) in your adf xml.

So you should use below in your xml:

```
<PROPERTY NAME="gender" DESCRIPTION="Gender">
        <STORAGE TYPE="VARCHAR" LENGTH="10"/>
        <INPUTFORM TYPE="RADIO" SOURCETYPE="STRING" RBVALUES="male,female,others" RBDESCRIPTIONS="male,female,others"/>
    </PROPERTY>
```

Comment: this really helped. Actually documentation clearly states that _you can input the label for each radio button using a static list of items that you provide with the `OPTIONDESCRIPTIONS` parameter_ . Thanks for highlighting with `RBVALUES` and `RBDESCRIPTIONS`.